# Newbie- Create mySQL Joomla database -- did not name mySQL db same as ISP - Can I rename?

Tags: mysql, database, joomla1.5, rename

New to Joomla and mySql environment. Created a Joomla test environment on localhost but did not name the mySql database to that of the target ISP.  Is there a way to rename the database so I can load to ISP?

Comment: Could someone edit that to remove the code tag ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understood your question and you actually installed joomla on localhost but now want to move it and its data to your isp hosting environement, you have two places where you need to change the db name (assuming joomla 1.5.6/latest):

```
JOOMLA_DIR\configuration.php
$db = 'your-db-name'

JOOMLA_DIR\LIBRARIES\JOOMLA\config.php
$db = 'your-db-name'
```

If your data is important, remember to make a backup first.